# How to enable Nvidia GPU driver in google cloud virtual machine instance in remote desktop

Tags: unity-game-engine, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gpu, photon

i am having a small problem which is quite critical actually, i run a Unity instance in a google cloud VM that work as a server for a small social experience in VR.

The thing is, if Unity is running without GPU, it starts clogging the processor and  the game kindda fails with many users, that is why i hired a eGPU Tesla P4, also, to run Unity, i must log in with Remote Desktop and hit Play.

The thing is, Windows disables the GPU when you go Remote Desktop, Unity opens without a GPU and the GPU is "Unknown" (in dxdiag), thats why i need to solve the RDP issue, i need to log in without disabling GPU acceleration so unity can open and go full power running my game, the server is like a player that doesnt show for the other clients, since its made in Photon PUN, its a weird hybrid, but it works as expected.

Now i have to solve this performance issue, i hope i am clear.

what i need to do now: log in with hardware acceleration (paying a lot for that online gpu and not using it).

What i have now : i log in without using the GPU, the CPU dies, and im wasting cash on the server.

thanks community!

PS: in a future i will use a headless server.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is a 'Windows' feature that many people have been complaining about. Basically windows switches to a generic driver when you are connecting via remote desktop. Try using an alternative remote desktop solution such as VNC.

Sources:

https://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_thread.php?id=7026

https://setiathome.berkeley.edu/forum_thread.php?id=70853